# Android list view swipe right to reveal button

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I wanted to achieve something like swipe right to reveal the button on each list view row in Android development.

I have a fully working list view which fetch and populate the data dynamically:

```
public class ProfilePastEvent extends Fragment{
View pastEventView;
Context context;
private ListView listview;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
public ArrayList<Event> _eventlist = new ArrayList<Event>();
EventController eventCtrl = new EventController();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listview = (ListView) pastEventView
            .findViewById(R.id.pastEventListview);

    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {

    });
    return pastEventView;
}

private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return _eventlist.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.profile_past_listview_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_dpastEventName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtPastEventName);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dpastEventName.setText(_eventlist.get(position)
                .getEventName().trim());


        return convertView;
    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_dpastEventName;
}
}
```

However, this list view works like user click on certain row to open up a new intent. How can I implement the swipe right to reveal 'View more' or 'Delete' button feature?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this library [AndroidSwipeLayout.](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) It has following type of animations:

[image]

**OR**

If you want to program this by your self, add following class. I've implemented this in one of the sample apps. I've found this on stackoverflow only, but don't remember from where.

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
private ListView list;

public MyGestureDetector(ListView list) {
    this.list = list;
}

//CONDITIONS ARE TYPICALLY VELOCITY OR DISTANCE    
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (INSERT_CONDITIONS_HERE)
        if (showDeleteButton(e1))
            return true;
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}

private boolean showDeleteButton(MotionEvent e1) {
    int pos = list.pointToPosition((int)e1.getX(), (int)e1.getY());
    return showDeleteButton(pos);
}

private boolean showDeleteButton(int pos) {
    View child = list.getChildAt(pos);
    if (child != null){
        Button delete = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_id);
        if (delete != null)
            if (delete.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and call this class as following:

```
MyGestureDetector(YOUR_LIST);
```

EDIT:

To detect swipe, use following conditions:

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
private static final int PEOPLE_FRAGMENT = 0;
private static final int PLACES_FRAGMENT = 2;
```

And conditions for swip up, down, right and left are: (In your case only one is needed, either right or left).

```
  if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
    Log.d("SWIPE", "right to left");
    return true; //Right to left
} else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
    Log.d("SWIPE", "left to right");
    return true; //Left to right 
}

//This will test for up and down movement. 
if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
    return false; //Bottom to top
} else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
    return false; //Top to bottom 
}
```

Now add that `showDeleteButton()` in either right to left or left to right. And also note that you can also detect small swipe by changing the values of `final` variables given above.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: But is there any way to implement it without re-code my code from scratch? Because I saw that it is using SwipeLayout rather than LinearLayout and I am afraid that the structure might be different

Comment: Cool I will try it out soon and update you again tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: hey sorry but what am I supposed to put for the "INSERT_CONDITIONS_HERE". Also, how do I call it?

Comment: its condition for detect the swipe. i.e touch is swipe or not. I'm edition my answer. And for calling part I've already added. @DeniseTan

Answer (score 2):

Hope This will help you,

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {


    private final String TAG = OnSwipeTouchListener.class.getSimpleName();
    ListView list;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private Context context;


    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx, ListView list) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        context = ctx;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public OnSwipeTouchListener() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void onSwipeRight(int pos) {
        //Do what you want after swiping left to right

        Log.e(TAG, "onSwipeRight: " + pos);

        mShopAdapter.swipeRight(pos);
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft(int pos) {

        //Do what you want after swiping right to left
        Log.e(TAG, "onSwipeLeft: " + pos);
        mShopAdapter.swipeLeft(pos);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        private int getPostion(MotionEvent e1) {
            return list.pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)
                    && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight(getPostion(e1));
                else
                    onSwipeLeft(getPostion(e1));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }


}
```

Then Attach to ListView

```
 mLstShopList.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity(),
                mLstShopList));
```

-mShopAdapter - Your adapter

you will get left and right swipe gesture inside your adapter.

Comment: Cool I will try it out and update you again tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use View pager for this inside list view as item here is code:

Activity.class:

```
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
            import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;


            public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_l);
                    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
                    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
                }

                private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                    LayoutInflater inflater;
                    ViewHolder viewHolder;

                    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
                        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    }

                    public int getCount() {
                        return 10;
                    }

                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        if (convertView == null) {

                            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                                    R.layout.list_item_view_pager, null);
                            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                            viewHolder.lst_vp = (ViewPager) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.lst_vp);


                            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }

                        viewHolder.lst_vp.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(TestActivity.this));



                        return convertView;
                    }
                }

                private class ViewHolder {
                    ViewPager lst_vp;
                }

                class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

                    Context mContext;
                    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

                    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
                        mContext = context;
                        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        return 2;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                        return view == object;
                    }

                    // This method should create the page for the given position passed to it as an argument.
                    @Override
                    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                        View view =   null;
                        if(position==0) {
                            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_row, container, false);
                        }else{
                            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.second_row, container, false);
                        }

                        container.addView(view);
                        return view;
                    }

                    // Removes the page from the container for the given position.
                    @Override
                    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                        container.removeView((View) object);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
                        if (position != 0 ) {
                            return 0.3f;
                        }
                        return 1f;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

List item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/lst_vp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="196dp">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>
```

View pager item first row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="First item "
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Second row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp">
          <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Delete "
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
```